# How can I center a logo image in an Omega theme?

Tags: 7, theming, media

I'm using Omega (a subtheme obviously) and am having trouble centering my logo image. I tried adding a `.logo-img` CSS class to my global.css file but it isn't doing anything. I added the following, but results are weird:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border: 4px solid;
```

I added the border to see the image field because when I save these settings, the image stays on the left, but the border extends all the way to the right.

So those settings end up in the logo image resulting like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMIsW.jpg (sorry I can't post images)

If I comment out the margin lines in the css file, the image stays the same.

I honestly don't know how to fix this. Is there a way to do this within my theme's settings? I can't find anything online or in the documentation.

Comment: Try Matt Galman's advice. Set Float none plus margin-left & right auto

Answer (score 1):

By default the Omega theme CSS floats the image within branding left. You'll have to set it to float none.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the region your logo is in. normally it comes in the branding region.

You have to set the position of region from the theme settings. you can set your region to appear in center. For that you have to change prefix columns in the branding region configuration.

For more info on weight, position, columns of regions : https://drupal.org/node/1416128